# I get Newwork error: Failed to fetch every time in apollo client

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Here is my App.js file. I run my query here.
I use apollo client instead of apollo-boost.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
    
const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    getAllSalons {
      id
      displayName
      email
    }
  }
`;
        
const App = (props) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(MY_QUERY);
  useEffect(() => console.log("-------", data), [data]);
  useEffect(() => console.log("-------", error), [error]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>KOMB COLLECTION</h1>
      {loading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>Data :)</h2>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is how I set up apollo client in index.js file
I set up authentication in my apollo client.

Here is all imports

```js
import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
```

I get failed to fetch error only with this endpoint but it works
fine in Postman and another endpoint works well with this code.

```js
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://13.125.142.93:3001/graphql",
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? token : "",
    },
  };
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I am new on graphql and don't know how to deal with this error. Also, I wasn't able to find any documentation for that.

I get this error on my console

```
Access to fetch at 'http://13.125.142.93:3001/graphql' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the backend has no configuration for cors. Configure cors on your backend and everything will work fine